# Printing Characters with my market program (C)

Tags: c

I wrote a market program that can sum up the price of the items you bought. Now I want to also print at the end the item that got selected and the quantity. How can I do that?

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main() {
int c,l=0,b=0,q=0;
float sum=0;
printf("Welcome to MH-Mart\n");
while (l<1) {
    printf("1.Bread\n");
    printf("Select a Category(If your done enter 11):\n");
    scanf("%d",&c);
    if(c==11){
        printf("YOUR TOTAL SUM=%f\n",sum);
        return 0;
        break;
    }
    if (c==1) {
        printf("Bread:\n1.Pita 1=1₪״\n2.Baguette 1=2.5₪ 
        \n3.WhiteBread1=1.5₪\nPlease select what you want:\n");
               scanf("%d",&b);
               printf("How many you want:\n");
               scanf("%d",&q);
               if(b==1){
                   sum=sum+(q*1);
               }
               if(b==2){
                   sum=sum+(q*2.5);
               }
               if(b==3){
                   sum=sum+(q*1.5);
               }
               }
               }

               }
```

Comment: Please run your code through `indent` or equivalent.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Be sure to take the
[tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and visit the [help
center](https://stackoverflow.com/help). What kind of suggestions do you want? As in, what's the problem that you can't solve - it's a bit hard to tell what's wrong with your code that should print the desired things when it's absent.

Comment: Your code has unbalanced braces.

Comment: Yes endless loop until they input number 11 which will break the loop and  print the sum

Comment: @trincot yes it's a part of the code that i wrote so some braces i didn't copy , the runs fine but all i need from it is to print the selections at the ned

Comment: Please add the missing braces. It is not clear which part belongs in which block. Don't leave us guessing ;-)